# Восстановление данных HTTP GET/POST запроса

Tags: http, golang

Допустим мне отключили интернет когда я мультипоточно отсылал запросы на сервер или ещё какой либо другой перебой в сети, как я могу восстановить все утерянные данные в запросе и сам запрос? Возобновиться после подключения к сети.

Comment: В go нет try..catch?

Comment: Опишите, что значит "восстановить утерянные данные"? Лучше всего пример с кодом.

Comment: @Ainar-G Уже не надо) Свою ошибку понял, обернул в цикл for если err != nil значит идет continue, если err не равняется nil идет break.